# Micheal arranges the letters in the word BANANA randomly. What is the probability that the As are all next to each other?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Micheal arranges the letters in the word BANANA randomly. What is the probability that the As are all next to each other?

What I did : 
So since there are 6 letters there are 6! or 720 possibilities.
However, the letters repeat (There are 2 Ns and 3 As), the actual # of possibilities would be 720/3!2!= 60

Then the number of possibilities would be 5!/2! because we combine the 3 As into one so there would be 5 "terms." Since the Ns repeat twice, we divide 5! by 2! to get 60 also.

See then we get the probability as 60/60, which can't be. What did I do wrong?

Comment: when you combine $AAA$ into a single "term" there are 4 terms to permute.  $\frac {4!}{2!} = 12$

Answer (score 2):

I agree the total number of rearrangements of the word `BANANA` is
$$
6 \cdot \binom{5}{2} = \frac{6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4}{2!} = 60.
$$

The actual possibilities are picked by fixing one of 4 places for the leading one of the `AAA` and picking one of the remaining $3$ places for the `B`, so there are a total of $4 \cdot 3 = 12$ ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case you have but $4$ characters, not $5$: $B, A^3, N_1, N_2$.

Answer (score 1):

When you combine the 3 A's into 1, there are 4 resulting terms, not 5.

Thus the number of possible permutations where the 3 A's are together is $4!/2 = 12$, and the probability is $12/60 = 1/5$